# How to clone an Android app as easy as possible?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am using an offline music player app to listen to the music files on my phone. Even though I am 70% happy with the app, there are a few things that annoy me. Since the app isnt getting updated anymore I want to make "my own version", where I fix the things I dont like.
Now the question is how do I do that without having to start building an Android app from 0?

I took a look into the apk file of the app in Android Studio (analyze apk) and it seems I have access to a lot of xml- and png-files the app uses. Before I have a closer look into them I wanted to ask if what I am planning is even possible and I can "import" all the layouts and logic of the original app into my own Android Studio project to mess around with them. Or is the case, that a crucial part of the source code is missing in the files from the apk, there is no short cut and I have to build the app from scratch?

Comment: You can't and this is illegal unless the app is open-source.

Comment: If you want to "make your own version" you would be better off using an existing open-source player as a base since the code and resources are in a understandable format. If you are truly looking at an abandoned APK, what your are describing is called "reverse engineering", and generally requires additional deep knowledge about Android.

Comment: @MorrisonChang That is probably the easiest way to achive what I want. thank you.